# jQuery .text gives empty to an element after .appenTo

Tags: jquery

I am using http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/ to change a select box.

Here is a example: http://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/bczrc/1/

I have a button when clicked gets the text inside an 'a' tag below it. I have two types of these 'a'. One that is part of the code on page load and the other that get dynamicly created with the select box plugin.

I can get the text from the 'a' tags that are part of the page but the dynamic ones I get empty string. I can see the text on the screen and the text is there as it should be when I inpect with firebug.

Why would `$(this).next(".menuItem").text()` not work with the dynamic one? I should see: 14' - €14.14

```
 //button to get text
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addToCart cart"></a>

<div id="sbHolder_51608882" class="sbHolder" tabindex="1">
    <a id="sbToggle_51608882" href="#" class="sbToggle"></a>
    <a id="sbSelector_51608882" href="#" class="sbSelector menuItem">14' - €14.14</a>
         <ul id="sbOptions_51608882" class="sbOptions" style="display: none;">
              <li><a href="#1" rel="1">6' - €6.66</a></li>
              <li><a href="#2" rel="2">12' - €12.12</a></li>
              <li><a href="#3" rel="3" class="sbFocus">14' - €14.14</a></li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

This works ok and is part of the page on load:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addToCart cart"></a>
<span class="price menuItem">12' - €12.99</span>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show the `appendTo` from the title or show the click context `$(this)` is used in. Can you add the relevant code as it makes a lot of difference how your click event is bound when accessing dynamic elements?

Comment: Your first snippet has a different structure as `.menuItem` is not next to the text link.

Comment: Hard to tell from what you've given us... but maybe the dynamic select needs to be called again to refresh its contents?

Comment: @FrancoisWahl; ...exactly.  This could be an issue with 'this'. The thing to do is to log the identity of the target element to verify what's actually being selected.

Comment: the .appenTo is part of the plugin, too much to paste here. The context of $(this) is $(".addToCart").click(function() {}

Comment: OK, then, in the click function registered to '.addToCart' dump the clicked element to the console to see if it is the one expected.  As in $('.addToCart').click( function(e) { console.log(e.target); })

Comment: When I dump $(this).next(".menuItem") it finds 2 elements. Could this be my problem as there 2 on the page after the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectations are incorrect. [**.next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) fetches the immediate next element (sibling). Look at your HTML and you see that the sibling of:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addToCart cart"></a>
```

Is :

```
<div id="sbHolder_51608882" class="sbHolder" tabindex="1">
```

If you want to access the anchor with class `.menuItem` which is **within** the `div` you need to go inside the `div` and `find` it.

```
$(this).next("div.sbHolder").find("a.menuItem").text();
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YNpEe/) - Display value from `.menuItem`

**Edit**
To address the 2 different scenarios you have one could apply some logic. This particular logic will work if you always have one or the other scenario. Off course, if you have completely random unpredictable scenarios this would not work.

```
$(".addToCart").on("click", function() {
    var $menuItem = $(this).next(".menuItem");

    if($menuItem[0] === undefined){
        $menuItem = $(this).next().find(".menuItem");
    }
    alert($menuItem.text());
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YNpEe/2/) - Find immediate next with `.menuItem` or child with `.menuItem` of immediate next

Comment: thanks for that, yes I can that I have the navigation through the dom incorrect. My problem with the above solution is that it will break the second type text I have on the screen. Also I have not included it but the plugin hides the select set to display none. This I see now interferes even when set to display none

Comment: I have create a full jsFiddle based on yours. You can see that I have included the select and the second type of button. http://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/bczrc/1/

Comment: @KeithPower: Now you even added a select following the first clicked anchor. If you have completely random markup in which your `.menuItem` could be in any sibling or any child you are going to have to `.each()` through the whole DOM following your clicked object. It might work but is not very efficient.